# Heroku shell. Write a csv file locally

Tags: python, csv, heroku

I need to query the **remote** db and write a **local** csv file with the data. I tried this code:

```
heroku run python manage.py shell

>>> from libros.models import LibrosDisponibles
>>> x = LibrosDisponibles.objects.all()
>>> 
>>> import csv
>>> with open("librosd_backup.csv", "wb") as f:
...   e = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
...   for l in x:
...     e.writerow([l.perfil, l.libro])
... 
>>>
```

It doesn't work the file is empty, I'm not writing to the right place of course. But, how can I solve this?

Comment: when you say 'locally' - are you wanting your script to write to your local computer? That's not possible via `heroku run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty, and not exactly via `heroku run`: execute a SQL statement via `pg:psql`, and use the `COPY` command. E.g. `heroku pg:psql -c 'copy my_table to stdout with csv header' > my_table.csv`. Very quick and convenient way to generate data for reports and other analysis. You can use a table name, or a full sql statement (e.g., `copy (select foo, bar from baz) to stdout with csv header`).

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html for info on `COPY`. You may wonder if you can use the 'to *filename*' version of the call... you can't. The filename is defined on the database server, which you have no access to.

If you need to honor some aspect of your Python logic, you could either -

1) <del>write a local script and use `heroku pg:credentials` to set `DATABASE_URL`</del> (actually, don't do this - if you forget to unset `DATABASE_URL` bad things <del>can</del>will happen...)

2) write an API endpoint that executes the code you wrote and stream directly (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-csv/) so you can call it locally via `cURL` (authenticated, of course)

Comment: Yup I ended up writing an API.

Comment: Thanks, this little heroku psql gem just saved me a bunch of work!